# Obscure NHibernate 3.2 Bulk Insert/HQL issue

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hql, bulkinsert

I have a requirement to do a 'bulk' insert of Event records into a database, based on a set of dates that the user passes in.

My event entity has a StartTime property and a StopTime property. The Event entity is the core entity in my application, and as such has a number of collections and entity references associated with it. It's a heavy entity.

So, my original code had me looping through the dates and doing something like this:

```
 Session.Save(new Event {StartTime=startdate, StopTime=endDate});
```

However this didn't scale well, and we felt the performance when inserting a few hundred dates.

So I had the thought of inserting all the dates into a temp table, but I could not figure out how to accomplish that with HQL.

So my next thought was to include all the dates as a subquery which got me the closest. Here is that approach:

```
var hql = "INSERT INTO Event (Code, Comment, Description, Status, StartTime, StopTime)
           SELECT ev.Code, ev.Comment, ev.Description, ev.Status, Dates.SDate, Dates.EDate
           FROM Event ev, 
                (
                    SELECT '1/2/2012 3:00:00 PM' as SDate, '1/2/2012 6:00:00 PM' as EDate
                    UNION ALL SELECT '1/3/2012 3:00:00 PM', '1/3/2012 6:00:00 PM' 
                    UNION ALL SELECT '1/4/2012 3:00:00 PM', '1/4/2012 6:00:00 PM'
                ) as Dates
           WHERE ev.Id = :sourceEventId";

Session.CreateQuery(hql).SetInt32("sourceEventId", @event.Id).ExecuteUpdate();
```

But the hql fails with very obscure error codes. My research online tells me that hql does not yet support UNION clauses.

Right now, I rewrote this approach as SQL and execute it through Session.CreateSQLQuery() and it works great. But I don't want to run it as SQL. That defeats the purpose of going with NHibernate anyway.

Is there another way I can approach this using HQL, (or any other NHibernate technology)?

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

### UPDATE

1. I forgot to mention that this is a legacy SQL Server database (I run unit tests on sqlite), and that all entities are generating their id's using SQL's Identity column.  So any attempts to batch fail.
2. As I explained in the comment below, I also tried the stateless session approach. NHibernate would fail telling me that I needed to save all my lazy loaded entities first. I temporarily got around that issue by removing those mappings, and it did work, and it was faster than regular session. But I still ended up having to insert every entity one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 1):

try using stateless session instead of session

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    session.Insert(yourObjects[i]);
}
tx.Commit();
}
```

[this link is also helpful](http://ayende.com/blog/4137/nhibernate-perf-tricks)

Moreover you can use ADO.net SqlBulkCopy instead of stateless session ,[check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply!  I forgot to mention that I did try the statelesssesion approach, and while it was faster than the regular session, you still have to insert 1 object at a time. Also when I tried stateless I ran into some issues with the lazyloaded relationships I have on my Event entity.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var sdates = new []{ "1/2/2012 3:00:00 PM", "1/3/2012 3:00:00 PM", "1/4/2012 3:00:00 PM" };
var edates = new []{ "1/2/2012 6:00:00 PM", "1/3/2012 6:00:00 PM", "1/4/2012 6:00:00 PM" };

var hql = "INSERT INTO Event (Code, Comment, Description, Status, StartTime, StopTime)
       SELECT ev.Code, ev.Comment, ev.Description, ev.Status, :sdate, :edate
       FROM Event ev
       WHERE ev.Id = :sourceEventId";

for(var i=0;i<sdates.Length;i++)
{
     Session.CreateQuery(hql).SetInt32("sourceEventId", @event.Id)
                             .SetString("sdate", sdates[i])
                             .SetString("edate", edates[i])
                             .ExecuteUpdate();
}
```

Probably you'll need to use DateTime instead of string and do some tweaks to the code, but it's an idea. Basically, you will be executing three commands instead of one but also instead of n+1 (and that was your scalation problem, right?)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!  Just so I'm clear: if I need to save 300 start/end date pairs, I would send up 300 insert statements?  I think this is what my initial attempt did (using Session.Save() not using hql though). But this still has the same problem of sending 1 insert per new date... What I really want to do is send up the full list of dates and run 1 query within the server, and save all the round trips.

Comment: Yep, I thought you only needed 3 :)

Comment: What about using bulk insert or just plain sql? The idea of using NHibernate is to solve the 90% of the scenarios and, when you hit a performance issue that cannot be solved using NHibernate (supposing this is the case), you go to sql.